# SAPui5 create entry with child entries

Tags: sap-fiori, sapui5

I want to create an entry and its child from the from ui5 so I used the approach of create entry the problem is I want the user to be able to update values of the child nodes so I did the following

```
var oParentContext = this._oODataModel.createEntry("/Parent",
{ changeId: "edit", properties: {object}, success: this._fnEntityCreated.bind(this), error: this._fnEntityCreationFailed.bind(this) });
    for (var i = 0; i < childArray.length; i++) {
                var child = childArray[i];

                aChildCtx = this._oODataModel.createEntry("/child", {
                    changeId: "edit",
                    properties: child,
                    context: oParentContext
                });
                aChildEntries.push(aChildCtx.getPath().substring(1));
            }
    this.getView().setBindingContext(oParentContext);
 // I attached also the relation to the front end
this.getView().getModel().setProperty("ToChild", aChildEntries, oParentContext);
```

In the view I did the binding to the relation ToChild to the table for the user to enter his values.

The display of the parent and child works however I am facing a problem that the view is issuing a get request to Odata with the temporary ID/ToChild. I couldn't find any solution for this. How should we do a deep insert in standard?

P.S. I don't want to use `deep_create`

Thanks

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

The create requests are currently being created asynchronously. The definitive parent ID will only be known in the frontend once the parent create request returns, but the requests to create the children are generated before this.

I can see two ways you could make sure the children will be created with the definitive parent id:

1. Send the parent and child create requests synchronously. Wait until the parent create request has returned succesfully before creating the children.
2. Send both as a change set. Let the implementation of the oData-service create the parent first and then the children with the now-created parent ID. (You are now setting changeId, the [API](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel%23methods/createEntry) specifies changeSetId)

Comment: Hello This problem is not comming during saving the entries but while the form beeing displayed.